# Disabling UNC message by changing manifest file - error message

Tags: c#, manifest, unc

To disable the UNC message requesting administrator credentials I changed the c# project app.manifest so `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false">` to `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false">`.

Now when running the application I get the following message:
[image]

The message appears only when running as non-administrator user. When running as administrator the application runs regularly.
Am I approaching my requirement correctly & if so how to avoid the message above to appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the manifest states level="AsInvoker" & the application attempts to perform an action which requires a higher permission level the cryptic message above will appear.